# Problem with creating public address - based on XPUB from ledger using HD-WALLET-DERIVE

Tags: php, ethereum

In short I have export xpub from Ledger-Live using https://github.com/dan-da/hd-wallet-derive:

```
{
"xpub": "xpub6BemYi..",
"index": 0,
"freshAddressPath": "44'/60'/0'/0/0",
"id": "libcore:1:ethereum:xpub6B...",
"blockHeight": 11140608
}
```

and try to use it with hd-wallet-derive:

```
./hd-wallet-derive.php -g --key=xpub6BemYi... --numderive=3 --coin=eth --path="m/44/60/0" --cols=address,xpub,path --format=jsonpretty

[
{
"address": "0xc42Ef07...",
"xpub": "xpub6LCcV6Xy...",
"path": "m/44/60/0/0"
},
...
]
```

but address is not matching with that from Ledger Live:

```
0x682ebE..
```

Do you know why there is a mismatch, how I should use --path parameter if I don't want to provide private key.

Comment: ...but that's not a programming question, unless you also extract a [mcve] as part of it. Please start with the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

xpub is "located" at very end of HD tree, so there is no path (just m/0).

You can not derive hardened path using xpub.

Full path is used when deriving from xpriv.